# Images name with Arabic letters not displaying in html page

Tags: php, jquery, html, image

I am trying to display images containing Arabic letters in their names using jquery...but the images are not getting displayed. Is there any way to rectify this  problem?

Comment: Yes, and it is called proper URL encoding.

Comment: There might be more than one reason for this, but url encoding is a good starting place. 

The javascript function to lookinto for this is:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

or php funciton (as this is tagged as php)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the multilingual characters in unicode document.. convert the document to UTF-8 document

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

When you put in some characters make sure your container tags have the following 2 properties set

```html
dir='rtl'
lang='ar'
```

```html
<p dir="rtl" lang="ar" style="color:#e0e0e0;font-size:20px;">رَبٍّ زِدْنٍي عِلمًا</p>
```

Comment: this is not my requirement.I need to display images with Arabic name in my HTML page

Comment: Please, add part of your code or all the code to help in a better way.

Comment: <img src="الخاسر/الخاسر.jpg"  alt="" > this is my code

Answer (score 0):

If you set the meta tag it will work

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<img src="http://falconimogollon.com/garbage/الخاسرالخاسر.png" title="arab" >
```

If you don't add the meta tag, the image won't appear